# Moving array between pages using PHP than select specific columns and save in table

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, codeigniter

Well i have a problem and need suggestions.

I am currently uploading a csv file which contains products data. There can be a lot of products. I am reading csv file using a library and than taking all the data in an array. Now i have a situation where i am stuck how to solve this.

Scanrio :

After uploading csv the user has a form where there are 9 specific columns. All the columns from csv should come into an array which will be displayed as dropdown. In the left side the form will contain specific fields and in the right side before each field there will be dropdown containing csv column names. After selecting the map button will be clicked and the columns will be selected from array and saved it into table. Now i dont know how i can hold data without saving into table while user selects the columns for mapping. What do i do? Shall i put the whole array in a hidden fields or else? Please suggest.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you may use session for this. Once everything is completed, you free your data from the session and run all SQL commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i dont know how i can hold data without saving into table while user selects the columns for mapping. What do i do? Shall i put the whole array in a hidden fields or else? Please suggest.

You could store them in session variables, that way whatever you store there is kept for each user separately and until that user logs out or some part of your code explicitly remove it. (Say, after you have discarted or made permanent the data on a database).

Hopefully, you are already using sessions, now give a look at [session variables at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Note: I have never used codeigniter, but a quick search show that it includes a [class for mamaging sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), look under FlashData, it seems to be the "codeigniter way" of doing it.

---

Edit:

Codeigniter sessions variables have a limit of 4KB, that may be enough for you, or maybe not. If it is not, you cal always use one of these alternatives:

1. Use the database to store the data, and store in the session variable some item id and user id to be able to retrive it.
2. Use a file, you can generate a random name and store it on the session variable, then store in the file whatever contents you need.

In case you can't handle the end of the sessions, you can have a expiration date stored in the database and a programmed task (are you able to use crons?) to remove the expired items from the temporary table (or file).

Although, beware! I don't know about the security of codeigniter... but, there are some risks. You may want to add a hidden "token" field with a random unique value associated with the user in a database table and an expiration date matching the lifetime of the session. You should create a new token each time you send a form, and after you recieve it verify if the token from the submited form matches a valid token for the user (identified by the session) in the database and if so, delete the token and proceed to process the rest of the form. If the token doesn't match or it is no longer valid, then the session has expired, somebody has been messing with cookies, or you have survived an attack (the case somebody recreates a post with an old token).

I repeat, I don't know of codeingiter security. But if I were the author of that framework, it would already have tokens implemented... so, chances are this security risk is already covered.

You can learn more about [Cross-site Request Forgery at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern).

Comment: If only codeigniter session woulnd't be based on cookies, wich have the 4kb or so limit. If DB is used as session storage that would work, though.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but if the user submits a csv which contains more than 100 records do you think i should still use sessions?

Comment: Thanks i see your point i can save a lot of data in text field this will do what i want. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the user data in a session?  This way you can pass it from page to page without putting it in the HTML(where it could be easily altered by a user).

Your best options are session or cookie.  Cookies are limited in that they can only contain a certain amount of data and you are limited to a certain amount of cookies since *cookies are stored on the clients machine.*  You can use sessions and this will save the information on the server.  Codeigniter limits sizes to 4kb.  To do this, in PHP you simply add

```
session_start()
```

to the top of every page you wish to use your session variables.

You should sanitize your user input.  To set your session variables you use the assignment operator (=).

```
$_SESSION['var'] = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'field_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
```

If you are using get you can use INPUT_GET.

If the user is not submitting the form, you could add an event listener via javascript and when form values are filled out you can store them in cookies and use PHP to extract the data from the cookie.

It is always best to sanitize and validate user data on the server.